# Combination of elements in a list leading to a sum K

Tags: python-3.x, combinations

I have been struggling with a programming problem lately, and I would appreciate any help that I could get.

Basically, the input is a list of numbers (both positive and negative, also, note that the numbers can repeat within the list), and I want to find the combinations of the numbers that lead upto a sum K.

For example,
List - [1,2,3,6,5,-2]
Required sum - 8

Output - Many combinations like : [5,3], [5,2,1], [6,3,1,-2]... and so on

I do understand that there are solutions available to this problem using module functions like **“itertools.combinations”** or **using recursion - subset of sum** (works efficiently only for positive numbers on the list), but I am looking for an efficient solution in python3 for lists upto a 100 numbers.

Any and every help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you want it to be efficient then it will not be using core python as it will take a lot of time, Using itertools is one of the best option

Comment: What u have done yet?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compute the sum over all subsets, not combinations.
This will never be efficient for 100 numbers (atleast in no way I know, either in C++ or in Python), because you need to actually compute all sums, and then filter.

This takes `O(n*2^n)` time using a method called Dynamic Programming - Sum over Subsets (DP-SOS). The following is the most efficient code possible:

```py
a, k = [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, -2], 8
dp = [0] * (1 << len(a))
for idx, val in enumerate(a):
    dp[1 << idx] = a[idx]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for mask in range(len(dp)):
        if mask & (1 << i):
            dp[mask] += dp[mask^(1<<i)]
answer = []
for pos, sum in enumerate(dp):
    if sum == k:
        answer.append([val for idx, val in enumerate(a) 
                       if (1 << idx) & pos])
```

Using itertools seems unnecessary to me, though you might get an answer in almost the same (or slightly longer) time, because the bitwise operators even in python are pretty fast.

Nevertheless, using itertools:

```py
from itertools import chain, combinations

a, k = [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, -2], 8

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

answer = list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == k, powerset(a)))
```

If you want to scale to 100 numbers, there might not be an exact solution, you would need to use heuristics and not compute the answer explicitly, because if the array is `[8, 0, 0, ...(100 times)]` then there are `2^99` subsets which you can anyways **never compute explicitly or store**.